# React, importing and using SVG sprite in a React component

Tags: reactjs, svg

I am new to SVG, I found a cool website called [icomoon.io](https://icomoon.io/), I selected and downloaded a few SVG icons, copied the sprite.svg file along with the SVG folder to the `/src` folder in my app, Now I am a little confused on what should I import to use the desired Icons, is it the sprite.svg then I specify the icon like so `import i_chat from '../sprite.svg#chat'` or import each icon separately from the SVG folder instead, and is there an external package i need to install to use the `<svg>` and `<use>` elements in my app? a use case would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: if you are using svg directly in the react markup it accepts. however, if you are trying to import it like import icon from './icon.svg', then you need to add a custom svg file handler in your webpack config

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any interactions with SVG elements (animation, transitions, etc.), you can deal with svg like any other image. There are several loaders for svg for webpack:

https://github.com/jhamlet/svg-react-loader
https://github.com/boopathi/react-svg-loader

React 15 version or above also supports svg.
For example:

```
render() {
  return (
    <svg>
      <circle cx="1" cy="2" />
    <svg>
  );
}
```

Hope, that helps